# Java Spark, can't update data with PUT nor PATCH

Tags: java, rest, http

i am trying to write a REST API that would return a full list of Players connected.
I Use Java Spark for the API however, only using GET the API returns a list of the actual connected players.
I would like to update the API response once in a while but i can't seem to wrap my head around on how i'm supposed to update the data returned when the API is accesed, as it doesn't.
I tried:
 - Using `get("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players);` -> It returns the list of the players correctly however it doesn't update (that's expected and i understand that GET method it's not made for modifying data)
 - Using `post("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players);` -> Accesing the URL returns 404 for whatever reason.
 - Using `put("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players);` -> Still 404
 - Using `patch("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players);` -> Nothing changes.

I I never worked with REST before and i'd really appreciate some help on what i am doing wrong or what i should read about.

Here's a code sample

```
    @Override
public void execute(CommandSender sender, String[] args) {
    Map<String,String> arguments = new HashMap<>();
    ArrayList<String> players = new ArrayList<String>();
    if (args.length == 0) {
        for (ProxiedPlayer p : main.getProxy().getPlayers()) {
            players.add(p.getDisplayName());
        }
        get("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players);

    }
```

[Result of the code above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Codwo.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you're missing a lot of fundamentals here. A RESTful API have different kinds of HTTP methods. `POST`, `PUT`, `GET`, `DELETE`, `PATCH`, `TRACE`, `OPTIONS` and so on.

You're using `get("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players)` so you're saying please create a REST resource path of `/api/playerlist` with HTTP method `GET`. That's why it returns 404 for every other methods.

It's possible to share resource path for different HTTP methods, e.g.,

```
post("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players)
put("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players)
get("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players)
delete("/api/playerlist", (req, res) -> players)
```

This will then allow you to call `/api/playerlist` using those 4 HTTP methods. Of course, which HTTP methods to use during which situation is actually subjective (mostly). If you change your `get()` to `post()` then post method won't return 404 anymore.

I suggest you read up on the best practices: https://www.vinaysahni.com/best-practices-for-a-pragmatic-restful-api

Comment: Thank you sir, but is there any i could update the entire list and also, if the URL is accesed how am i supposed to show the updated information? I read on best practices and other sites that using PUT can update only a specific Player (in my case).
I would like to update the entire endpoint /playerlist at an interval and also display the updated version once the url is accesed, i searched on multiple websites but no hope for me.

Comment: Technically speaking, you can use even `GET` to update something. HTTP methods is a suggestion, not a restriction but `PUT` is the convention. You just  need a `controller` with `put()` method and you perform your update logic there. Then the response that's returned by this `put()` method will contain the updated players

Comment: I actually managed to fix my code yesterday and was able to update the shown list using different HTTP methods, my mistake was a logic mistake and that's why it wasn't updating.
Thank you for your time and help!